# Lock Columns while still allowing formulas to calculate in a table

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-tables

I have a table where the highlighted cells contain formulas in which I do not want anyone to be able to edit:

[image]

The reason I have built a table is so that once I enter new data on the forth row for instance, the formulas in the highlighted cells should auto calculate themselves.

[image]

The issue I am having is trying to prevent any edits to the formulas I have in the highlighted cells while still have the formula automatically calculate once I have filled data for column 1 and 4 for new rows added.

What I did try was locking the cells by doing the following:

1. Highlighted all of the cells in the worksheet
2. Made sure that the highlighted cells were unlocked:

[image]

3. Locked the columns where the formulas would be:

[image]

4.Selected Protected Sheet:

[image]

5. Now that the highlighted columns are protected and no one is able to edit them, I lost the ability to have those columns auto calculate for new rows when I enter new data in new rows:

[image]

Comment: Suggestion: Have a VBA code that runs on worksheet_change and check and/or overwrite the formulas in these columns to make sure they are not tampered with

Comment: So B and C don't autofill? Why not create a formula that returns nothing when nothing is in D?

Comment: That's a problem with Excel tables.  If you lock the sheet to protect the formula  you can't add rows/columns to a table as the sheet is locked.  It's a problem I hope MS does something about.  Some more info here:  [Excel: tables in protected sheets, cannot expand](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/excel-tables-in-protected-sheets-cannot-expand/6c16b12e-9da2-4867-be1b-dc900a833786)